# how install SSL cert (DV) DNS CNAME-Based Authentication in GoogleCloud Compute engine?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dns

I just bought SSL cert in COMODO, Product Name  PositiveSSL (DV),
and I am now confused how to proceed further to enable SSL  in my nginx web server, linux VM host, running in Google Cloud Compute engine.

I got these instructions:

> DNS CNAME Record:  Since you selected DNS CNAME-Based Authentication, Here are general instructions on how to complete this step:
>   Login to your domain's DNS provider (typically the registrar of your domain)
>   Go to the DNS Zone Manager to amend the records.
>   Create the following CNAME record using hash values below:
>   DomainAlias / Host hostname__#hash#.hostame
>
> For the Point to , Please enter #hash#.comodoca.com in each record per domain. Set the TTL to 3600 or the lowest possible option. Click Save and wait for the record to propagate (i.e. 15 minutes).

so facts are these:

> SSL cert is from COMODO,
>   DNS name was registered in goDaddy,
>   VM host is running in GoogleCloud,
>   and nameservers in godaddy portal was changed to google nameservers, because hosting is in GoogleCloud...
>   and SSL cert is in Validation Status:   Awaiting Validation (Full)

...so I was googling how to add DNS CNAME-Based Authentication (according instructions from COMODO), but I found only below advice for GSuite...
https://support.google.com/a/topic/1615038?hl=en

or some howtos for OS/nginx installation
https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/nginx-ssl-installation/

In GoDaddy told me that this is out of scope of them, becasue nameservers are in scope of Google,

So can somebody help me what are exatcly next steps in my case ?
I am aware that I need also setup then OS/nginx  part, but  I think that  I need first setup this DNS CNAME-Based Authentication.

> > I found below howto.. but after adding CNAME in Google cloud DNS - still not working.
> >     https://www.geocerts.com/support/domain-control-validation-by-dns-cname-method

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems that CERT is Actvated already, I forget to check my mail... :)
ok going to setup my webserver.